# "Module parse failed: Unexpected token." Trying to import Bootstrap 5 in VueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-5

I encountered a strange error trying to add bootstrap 5.1.3 to VueJS 2.5.2

```
error  in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1243:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|   _getConfig(config) {
|     config = { ...Default$a,
|       ...Manipulator.getDataAttributes(this._element),
|       ...(typeof config === 'object' ? config : {})

 @ ./src/main.js 11:0-19
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

This is the problematic Vue App component:

```
import App from './App'
import store from './store/index'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "bootstrap"


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

If I remove the `import "bootstrap"` line, it compiles. But once I add `import "bootstrap"` it breaks.

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "qs": "^6.10.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
```